# Get Xpath for HTML elements from .asp web page

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, firebug

I need to scrape this HTML page ...

http://www.asl1.liguria.it/templateProntoSoccorso.asp

[image]

.... using PHP and XPath to get the values like 2 in

Codice bianco: **2**

(NOTE: you could see different values in that page if you try to browse it ... it doesn't matter ..,, they changing dinamically .... )

I can't get the XPath for those values using Mozilla Firebug as usually I do: any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $url = 'http://www.asl1.liguria.it/templateProntoSoccorso.asp';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $Number = $xpath->query('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]');

    foreach( $Number as $node )
    {
      echo "Number: " .$node->nodeValue;
      echo '<br>';
      echo '<br>';
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Note that [Firebug's development is discontinued](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) in favor of the Firefox built-in developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved ... here you are the right code

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $url = 'http://www.asl1.liguria.it/templateProntoSoccorso.asp';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $Number = $xpath->query('(//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[1]/text())[1]');

    foreach( $Number as $node )
    {
      echo "Number: " .$node->nodeValue;
      echo '<br>';
      echo '<br>';
    }    
?>
```

that print ....

Codice bianco: 2

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

1. Value from First element:

   ```
   substring-after(//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[1]/text(), ":")
   ```
2. From second:

   ```
   substring-after(//div[@class="datiOspedaleCodici"]/div[2]/text(), ":")
   ```

   ...etc

Just increase index in `/div[x]` to get next value

Comment: I've updated my initial question with a PHP code in which I've tried to use the xPath (complete), but it doesn't work ....